# How to add custom field option with menu?

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, menus, admin-menu

Please take a look at below image.

[image]

Here we can see URL, Navigation Label & Title Attribute under Menu Structure >> Home.
I need there a more option called "Data Description".

I have a task to write menu code like below with wordpress.

```
<a href="[URL]" data-description="[Data Description]">[Navigation Label]</a>
```

Is there any option to display my menu dynamically like this?
Also It should support "current-menu-item" class on current page.

I'm a wordpress theme developer & also have some knowledge of plugins development, If there are any way please suggest me.

Comment: Have you researched and tried anything so far? If so you should show what you got to give others a better starting point to help you.

Comment: Actually, have knowledge & also used in my too many themes for simple menu link like `<a href="[URL]">[Navigation Label]</a>` but today I wanted there `data-description="[Data Description]"` & want know the solution for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link helps me to solve my problem. : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-show-the-description-of-the-menu